# Unknown Str_Replace On URL

Tags: php, url, str-replace

I am trying to understand this one line of code below:

```
str_replace('../', '', $route);
```

Basically it says replace `'../'` with nothing in `$route`

```
$route = 'information/information&information_id=4';
```

from the url `'index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4'`

But there is no ../ in the $route variable. Is it some sort of regex? If yes, what does it exactly do. Thanks guys.

Comment: As @brain_d and @Mchl have said, it's probably a security measure.  But that sort of thing should be detected and an error given, not just removed.  Anyone putting `../` into the string is 100% guaranteed an attack.

Comment: Why give them an error message? Log their IP and time, but otherwise give them no clue anything happened :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that it replaces `"../"` with an empty string. It is not regex. There is no occurence of it in your example, but *there could be*.

It might be used for some sort of security to prevent you from going back up the directory structure from the document root.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no `../` in the string, this will replace nothing. It's not a regex (see `preg_replace()` for that. It's just precaution against someone trying to pass invalid path (starting with `../`), which could potentially be an attempt of accessing files outside of webserver's document root (in other words, a hacking attempt).